# Return type of this for inherited TypeScript classes not working

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a base class where inheriting classes must implement a method that returns objects of the same type as itself.

```js
abstract class Base {
  abstract clone(): this;
}

class Impl extends Base {
  clone(): this {
    return new Impl();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error.

> Type 'Impl' is not assignable to type 'this'.
>     'Impl' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Impl'.(2322)

I can work around this with casting magic:

```js
abstract class Base {
  abstract clone(): this;
}

class Impl extends Base {
  clone(): this {
    return new Impl() as this;
  }
}
```

...but I don't understand why this is necessary. Why is a `new Impl()` not of type `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says that, if you subclass `Impl`, function `clone()` of your resulting subtype won't fit defined constraints.

```js
class Impl2 extends Impls {
}

const impl2 = new Impl2();
impl2.clone(); // method would return Impl type, instead of Impl2 type, so `this` is not correct constraint.
```

As of this moment, while there is a workaround to prevent further inheritance from `Impl` class by using`private contructor()`, compiler/language service will still report the error, as there is no way to mark class as `sealed`/`final`.

Comment: Oh, thanks that's more clear now. And since TypeScript can't let you make a class final, I guess there's no way around having to cast, eh?